# How to create text fading effect when user swipes across tabs using PageIndicator

Tags: java, android, viewpagerindicator

What's the minimum amount of effort required to change Jake Wharton's **TitlePagerIndicator** 
into one that produces the text fading effect you see on Google Play Store as you swipe 
between tabs? I think the key lies in modifying **onDraw()** but that requires me figuring out his code and his math. If there's an easier solution I'd prefer that.

I also tried **TitlePagerIndicator.setFadingEdgeLength(100)**, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I am aware you have to do **TitlePagerIndicator.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true)** but 
still no fading effect whatsoever.

Here's the code based off from one of Jake's samples:

```
public class SampleTitlesStyledMethods extends BaseSampleActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_titles);

        mAdapter = new TestTitleFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator = indicator;
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        indicator.setBackgroundColor(0x18FF0000);
        indicator.setFooterColor(0xFFAA2222);
        indicator.setFooterLineHeight(1 * density); //1dp
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorHeight(3 * density); //3dp
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Underline);
        indicator.setTextColor(0xAA000000);
        indicator.setSelectedColor(0xFF000000);
        indicator.setSelectedBold(true);

        //my code, doesn't seem to do anything though...
        indicator.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        indicator.setFadingEdgeLength(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs an answer!  Did you figure it out Barney Hsiao?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but you should check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876078/creating-blurring-effect-on-both-sides-of-viewpagerindicator) it worked great for me