# Creating blurring effect on both sides of ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android

I realize, for Google Play market, they have "blurring" effect on left right (See "Paid" on left, and "Trend" on right, as in attachment)

I was wondering, is it possible to achieve such effect using [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/)? As from the demo I saw, we can customize various indicators (from line to triangle). But I haven't seen an example, which create "blurring" effect on left right side.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering, is it possible to achieve such effect using
>   ViewPagerIndicator?

You could extend the `TitlePagerIndicator` class and simply draw the fading edges yourself:

```
public class TitlePageIndicatorFade extends TitlePageIndicator {

    private GradientDrawable mDrawableLeft, mDrawableRight;
    private static final int FADE_SIZE = 30;

    public TitlePageIndicatorFade(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TitlePageIndicatorFade(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TitlePageIndicatorFade(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mDrawableLeft = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {
                        Color.parseColor("#F9F9F9"),
                        Color.parseColor("#00000000") });
        mDrawableRight = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, new int[] {
                        Color.parseColor("#F9F9F9"),
                        Color.parseColor("#00000000") });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mDrawableLeft.setBounds(0, 0, FADE_SIZE, getHeight());
        mDrawableRight.setBounds(getWidth()- FADE_SIZE, 0, getWidth(),
                getHeight());
        mDrawableLeft.draw(canvas);
        mDrawableRight.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```